# What structured data is used for the license info in Google Images?

Tags: structured-data, google-image-search, licenses

Google Images allows filtering by copyright license - What is used for it: Microdata, Microformats or RDFa?

Comment: Your SVG question is answered here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13848/do-search-engines-index-text-contained-in-svg-elements

Comment: thanks. The question was on licnese info. As I understand creative commons recomends using rel=license. But RDF is more natural in xml word. And possibly google may use different formats for html and svg content.

Comment: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2009/08/specifying-images-license-using-rdfa.html ?

Comment: @JohnMueller - thanks. I'll try and report is it working or not. 
p.s. I hate this video fashion. Wouldn't It be much more easier and helpful - to have a couple of paragraphs?