# Will Google index text in inline SVG that was rendered through JavaScript?

Tags: seo, javascript, googlebot, svg

As far as I know the Google bot will index text inside of inline SVG, [this has been answered already](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13848/do-search-engines-index-text-contained-in-svg-elements). However I don't know this applies to text that was generated through JavaScript.

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/ruhizorufe/edit?html,js,output

Will the text of the word cloud be indexed?

Answer (score 1):

As long as Google has access to your javascript files (ie: your robots.txt file doesn't exclude access to the javascript file in question) then Google will be able to index the page with no worries.